# Duda con el patrón Singleton

Tags: c++, singleton

Copiando un ejercicio sobre Singleton, veo que hay que especificar el valor del miembro estático de la clase fuera del constructor. Al principio no lo había hecho y obtuve el error:

> Singleton.cpp|26|referencia a `Singleton::instance' sin definir|

Esta es la clase:

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_H
#define SINGLETON_H
#include <iostream>


    class Singleton
    {
    public:
        static Singleton* getInstance();
        int dameN();
        void tomaN(int num);
    
    protected:
        Singleton();
        virtual ~Singleton();   
    
    private:
        static Singleton *instance;    
    };
    
    #endif // SINGLETON_H
```

y la implementación:

```
#include "Singleton.h"

//Singleton* Singleton::instance=nullptr;<--esta linea tal cual esta comentada provoca el error

Singleton::Singleton()
{
    std::cout << "Creating singleton" << std::endl;
}

Singleton::~Singleton()
{
    //dtor
}

Singleton* Singleton::getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == nullptr)
            instance = new Singleton();
        else
            std::cout << "Getting existing instance"<<std::endl;

        return instance;
    }
```

Mi duda es saber por qué tengo que definir de forma específica el puntero miembro de esta forma:

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance=nullptr;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) dice:

> The static keyword is only used with the declaration of a static
> member, inside the class definition, but not with the definition of
> that static member.

En español: la palabra `static` se utiliza dentro de una clase para **declarar** los miembros estáticos de la misma.

Por lo tanto, debes inicializarla en otra parte. Eso es lo que haces con:

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance=nullptr;
```

---

Te sugiero que devuelvas una referencia en lugar de un puntero y que la instancia *viva* dentro de la función con [almacenamiento estático](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables). Así:

```
class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton& getInstance();
    int dameN();
    void tomaN(int num);

protected:
    Singleton();
    virtual ~Singleton();
};

Singleton& Singleton::getInstance()
{
    // Aunque no lo parezca, se llama al constructor por defecto. Puedes utilizar otro explícitamente.
    // Así mismo, si el constructor que se intenta utilizar no existe o fue eliminado obtendrás errores.
    static Singleton instance;
    return instance;
}
```

La ventaja de esta manera es que te libras del problema de liberar la memoria. Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##dVE9a8MwEN39K44UQkrI0KlgO13apUuWrl3U09UI9GGkU5eS/PSqclQcuWANQrz37r27E47jYUBM6U5Z1FES9MoF9iTMUxODsgNYYSiMAgkCy65pUIsQ4C1TmtjZBvL5vt5j/NAK2@t7OoEFK7xJtzAQv9oMW6TdfTcLlWWQOeZUg19OSWBnxGk38TaaP7JkeceETPIWN@csXJTnKDRcarZYnPMwM9q2laCMgy4y9D1snl3u2Udk59/tpmvOi7rLeuELrdZtobJYrKV4/N9d3lERlNE8cfQ1mL2nLRmh5jaqLAHH1bxcm9IPfmoxhHTIf3zE/f7h8Rc).